# Conditional synchronization, lock

Tags: c#, .net, synchronization, locking

I have a question on how to implement a list/dictionary in the way it will not lock while reading and is locked while writing.
Sample of my code from GitHub project: [TextProcessorsCache.cs](https://github.com/NickResh/TextExtensionsNet/blob/master/src/TextExtensionsNet.Library/Processors/TextProcessorsCache.cs)

```
/// <summary>
/// Cache of text processors that can be re-used as they do not have
/// state
/// </summary>
public static class TextProcessorsCache
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, ITextProcessor> cache;

    static TextProcessorsCache()
    {
        cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, ITextProcessor>();
    }

    public static ITextProcessor GetInstance<T>() where T: class, ITextProcessor, new()
    {
        return cache.GetOrAdd(typeof(T), new T());
    }
}
```

I want to get rid of the `ConcurrentDictionary<Type,ITextProcessor>` field, instead I want any calls to cache check the existence of value by key, but to write it will lock & suspend any reads until the value is written into dictionary

Impl with ReaderWriterLock.

```
public static class TextProcessorsCache 
{
private static readonly Dictionary<Type, ITextProcessor> cache;
private static ReaderWriterLockSlim locker = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

static TextProcessorsCache() 
{
  cache = new Dictionary<Type, ITextProcessor>();
}

 public static ITextProcessor GetInstance<T>() where T: class, ITextProcessor, new()
 {
     ITextProcessor processor;
     locker.EnterReadLock();

         cache.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out processor);

     locker.ExitReadLock();

         if (processor == null) 
         {  
              locker.EnterWriteLock();

              if (cache.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out processor))
              {
                   locker.ExitWriteLock();
                   return processor;
              }

              processor = new T();
              cache[typeof(T)] = processor;

              locker.ExitWriteLock();                 
         }
     return processor;
 }   
}
```

Comment: You must have some kind of synchronization, otherwise you will have to rewrite the dictionary implementation from the ground up to never modify existing data structures and only add to it, otherwise you risk that a writer, though you only allow one writer at a time, temporarily constructs a corrupt data structure for a read operation that may execute concurrently.

Comment: If you do stick with using `ConcurrentDictionary`, don't use `return cache.GetOrAdd(typeof(T), new T());` Use `return cache.GetOrAdd(typeof(T), (key) => new T());` instead. The first one will **always** `new` up a `T`. The second won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach is to use generics to ensure that only one instance of each implementation is ever instantiated, as per below. *The `Cache` class will ensure that only one of each `T` (type) is instantiated (for all calls to `Get` for that `T`).*

*You would need to profile to confirm this implementation is faster / slower than your current implementation.*

```
using System;

namespace Sample
{
    public class Runner
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            TextProcessorsCache.GetInstance<TextProcessor1>();
            TextProcessorsCache.GetInstance<TextProcessor2>();
            TextProcessorsCache.GetInstance<TextProcessor1>(); // this should not write to the console
            TextProcessorsCache.GetInstance<TextProcessor2>(); // this should not write to the console

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public static class TextProcessorsCache
    {
        public static ITextProcessor GetInstance<T>() where T : class, ITextProcessor, new()
        {
            return Cache<T>.Get();
        }
    }

    static class Cache<T> where T : class, ITextProcessor, new()
    {
        internal static T value;
        static Cache()
        {
            value = new T();
        }

        public static T Get()
        {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public interface ITextProcessor
    {
    }

    public class TextProcessor1 : ITextProcessor
    {
        public TextProcessor1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1 constructed");
        }
    }

    public class TextProcessor2 : ITextProcessor
    {
        public TextProcessor2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("2 constructed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! A good approach. You use static classes because they're thread-safe when constructing?

Comment: Basically yes. It is guaranteed the static constructor will run only once (per type).